# How to find the number of atoms of an element in $x$ amount of a compound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chemistry

Lets say I am given a certain mass of a compound. Additionally, the number of moles of the compound itself are known, as well as its molar mass. How can I, using an equation, find the number of atoms (in moles) of an element in said compound?

After trying myself, I derived the equation, $A = \frac{pm}{a}$, where $A$ is the number of atoms, $p$ is the percent composition, $m$ is the mass of the compound, an $a$ is the AMU measure of the element. Logically, it seems this would work. However, it does not algebraically. This is because $p = \frac{a}{M}$, where $M$ is the AMU measure of the compound. If you factor that in, you can see that both $a$'s cancel each other out, so I end up with the same answer for any element of the same compound.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is the compound composed wholly of a single molecule? Otherwise I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: The compound is either ionic or molecular. The number of the compound itself is variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means, but: you know the number of atoms of the required type contained in each molecule of the compound, and you can figure out the number of molecules of the compound from the data you are given. Can't you multiply the two together?

Comment: If you know the number of moles of the compound $n_c$, the number of moles of an element $n_e$ is just $n_e = n_c q$ where $q$ is the number of atoms of the element in the compound.  Do you not know $q$?

Comment: @ex0du5 That is correct. I am looking for $q$, which I can then convert to moles using Avagadro's constant.

Comment: @rogerl Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the formulas for percent composition and the number of moles cancel each other out. I always end up with the same answer for any given compound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m$ is the mass of the compound in grams, and $M$ is the AMU mass of the compound, there are $N_A \frac mM$ molecules of the compound, where $N_A$ is Avogadro's number.  The mass of your atoms is then $mp$ and the number of atoms is $A=N_A\frac {mp}a$

Comment: This seems to be the same as what I have. The percent composition is equal to $\frac{a}{M}$, where $M$ is the AMU measure of the compound. Since $\frac{a \div m}{a} = 1 \div m$, I end up with the same answer all the time.

Comment: $p=\frac {na}M$, where $n$ is the number of atoms of this sort per molecule.  Then $A=N_A \frac {nm}M$.  Dividing out the $a$ is not a problem.  Try it with the hydrogen in 20 grams of $H_2O$.  You need the fact that there are two atoms of hydrogen

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is the mass of an element in grams, and $M$ is the AMU mass of the element, then the number of atoms is given by $N_A \frac{m}{M}$, where $N_A$ is Avogadro's number.

The chemical formula for the compound tells you the ratio of elements in the compound. Let's say we are talking about water. Hydrogen is 1, Oxygen is 16. Thus in every 18 kg of water, there is 16 kg of oxygen and 2 kg of hydrogen. Let's say you had 26 kg of water. Then we have 4 kg of hydrogen. Then just plug this into the equation above for the answer.

Comment: This seems to be the same as what I have. The percent composition is equal to $\frac{a}{M}$, where $M$ is the AMU measure of the compound. Since $\frac{a \div m}{a} = 1 \div m$, I end up with the same answer all the time. While your logic is solid, it seems the algebra causes some trouble.

Comment: To finish off the computation, we note that 1 mole of hydrogen weighs 1 gram. We have 4 kg, so we have 4000 moles of Hydrogen

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have dreadfully overcomplicated my issue. It looks like I just needed to divide the mass of the compound by the molar mass of the element, which gave me the quantity of the element in moles.